# Equivalent way of rewriting a two-component mixture

Tags: probability, distributions, mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

I'm confused on the following equivalent way of rewriting a two-component mixture.

---

Consider the two-component conditional mixture
$$
F(z|x)=\lambda F_1(z|x)+(1-\lambda)F_2(z|x)
$$
where all the $F$'s are conditional CDFs and $\lambda\in (0,1)$.

**A1:** Assume that $F(z|x)=0$ $\forall z\leq 0$.

**A2:** Assume that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}zdF_j(z|x)$ exists $\forall j\in \{1,2\}$.

---

Consider a random variable $Z_j$ with CDF conditional on $x$ equal to $F_j(\cdot|x)$ $\forall j \in \{1,2\}$.

Define the random variable
$$
\epsilon_j\equiv Z_j-\int_{\mathbb{R}}zdF_j(z|x)
$$
$\forall j \in \{1,2\}$. 
Let $G_j(\cdot|x)$ denote the CDF of $\epsilon_j$ conditional on $x$ $\forall j \in \{1,2\}$. 
Then, 
$$
F_j(z|x)=G_j\Big(z-\int_{\mathbb{R}}zdF_j(z|x)\Big|x\Big)
$$
$\forall j \in \{1,2\}$. 
Hence we can rewrite
$$
(\star) \hspace{1cm} F(z|x)=\lambda\times G_1\Big(z-\int_{\mathbb{R}}zdF_1(z|x)\Big|x\Big)+(1-\lambda)\times G_2\Big(z-\int_{\mathbb{R}}zdF_2(z|x)\Big|x\Big)
$$

---

**Question 1:** I believe that A1 implies that $F_j(z|x)=0$ $\forall z\leq 0$ and $\forall j\in \{1,2\}$. Is this correct? If this is true, then can we say that, for example, A1 implies that $F_1(\cdot|x)$ and $F_2(\cdot|x)$ **cannot** be normal CDF?

---

**If I'm correct about Question 1:**

**Question 2:** 
A1 remains valid also under the new representation of the mixture $(\star)$. However, I can't see how  $G_1\Big(z-\int_{\mathbb{R}}zdF_1(z|x)\Big|x\Big)$ and  $ G_2\Big(z-\int_{\mathbb{R}}zdF_2(z|x)\Big|x\Big)$ can be zero for negative values of their arguments, given that the definition of $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$ does not prevent these two random variables from having negative realisations.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about Question 1. Since both $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$ are positive, while $F_j(z\mid x)\ge0$, the only way for $\lambda F_1(z\mid x)+(1-\lambda)F_2(z\mid x)$ to be zero is if both $F_1(z\mid x)$ and $F_2(z\mid x)$ are zero. So it follows that $F_1(\cdot\mid x)$ and $F_2(\cdot\mid x)$ can never be the cdf of a Normal distribution.

For question 2, you are misreading the conclusion. The same argument as above shows that $G_j(z-\int zdF_j(z\mid x)\mid x)$ equals zero for all $z\le 0$. However, this does not imply that $G_j(t\mid x)$ equals zero for all $t\le0$, which seems to be your conclusion.